# If $\omega \in \Omega^q(M)$, and $(\omega|_{U})_p = 0$, is $\omega_p = 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have a manifold $M$ and $\omega \in \Omega^q(M)$, considered an open subset $U$ of $M$, and choose a point $p \in M$, is it true that $(\omega|_{U})_p=0 \rightarrow \omega_p=0$? With $\omega|_{U}$ I mean the pull-back of $\omega$ by the embedding $F:U\to M$. The converse is obviously true, but this implication?

Comment: Have you tried just looking at a local expression for $(\omega\mid_U)_p$ and comparing it with $\omega_p$? They are essentially the same objects at $p$.

Comment: @AwfullyWeeBilly Yes, but I'm not sure that the implication is true. Maybe a form can be 0 restricted to U and not zero M\U...

Comment: @AwfullyWeeBilly In particular, if $p \in$ M\N how you could say that are the same object?

Comment: the implication that you wrote is obviously true. It doesn't even talk about $M\backslash{}U$; all you care about is what happens at **one point**, namely, $p$. Sure, a form can vanish on an open subset and not everywhere else, but that's not the issue here. It wasn't the question you asked, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\omega \in \Omega^k(M) = \Gamma(M, \bigwedge^kT^*M)$, so $\omega$ is a smooth map $\omega : M \to \bigwedge^kT^*M$ such that $\omega_p := \omega(p) \in (\bigwedge^kT^*M)_p \cong \bigwedge^kT^*_pM \cong \left(\bigwedge^kT_pM\right)^*$ for each $p \in M$. Therefore, $$\omega_p : \underbrace{T_pM\times\dots\times T_pM}_{k\ \text{copies}} \to \mathbb{R}$$ is a skew-symmetric multilinear map.

Now $\omega|_U = \omega\circ i_U \in \Omega^k(U)$, so for any $p \in U$, $$(\omega|_U)_p = \omega|_U(p) = (\omega\circ i_U)(p) = \omega(i_U(p)) = \omega(p) = \omega_p.$$ Therefore, $(\omega|_U)_p = 0$ (i.e. it is the zero map) if and only if $\omega_p = 0$.